# Downloading a package

Tags: ros, kinect, package, download

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new with ROS, so I think this question is easy to answer, but I haven't found it in FAQ.

I am trying to download the kinect_camera package, from this site:
http://ros.org/wiki/kinect_camera

The problem is that the source address is not like all other packages I've seen. The source address is:
bzr lp:cyphy   or   lp:cyphy

I usually type (to download a package):
svn co

and this works with a normal address (eg. http://svn.pointclouds.org/ros/trunk/perception_pcl_unstable/pcl    for a pcl package)

What should I do to download the kinect_camera package? I use Ubuntu.

Thank you in advanced, if the question was already answer please forgive me, I didn't found it.

Dani

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12213/downloading-a-package/) by [BLaS](https://answers.ros.org/users/1491/blas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2011-12-04

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
There are different version controls like hg, svn, bzr etc. Bazaar is the version control you are talking about. The command for checking out from bzr is

```
bzr checkout <https://link> <local_directory_path>
```

you can google to know more about this version control.

Hope this helps,
Karthik

---

Originally posted by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) with karma: 2831 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3